# How to use selectpicker and filter typing text

Tags: jquery, css, select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I implemented [selectpicker](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) to style select but I have no idea how to add filtering by type text like in [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html). Does anyone have got idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean grouping options by some parentgroup?

Like this?

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: No, i mean to type text in field and filter expanded results.

Comment: Are you referring to https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple ?

Comment: Yes. But problem is use select2 with selectpicker. Selectpicker creates own ul>li structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `data-live-search` prop/attribute setting it to `true`.

Official link with working examples:

https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search